# C Linked list card game and getting weird results due to fatal bug

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

I'm very new to coding in C (and therefore the silly exercise I am working on). The code is supposed to create a linked list that simulates a deck of cards being held in hand.

The code is meant to: (1) remove the first card and place it on the table, then (2) take the new first card and place it at the end of the deck held in hand.

What is very weird is that my codes works well for the first few iterations, then suddenly it starts endlessly printing on the screen.  Unfortunately my knowledge of C is not good enough to understand what the bug is.  I've tried different variations of code and nothing seems to work.

I would greatly appreciate your input.  I've attached my code and the print out.  I have also highlighted the function that prints to screen.  I'm guessing the problem is with the function add_to_desk().

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} *Node_t;

void print_list(Node_t root) {
    while (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        root = root->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

Node_t first_to_last(Node_t root, Node_t head){
    Node_t next_root, last_root;
    // get the pointer to the second element
    next_root = root->next;
    // unlink first element
    root->next = NULL;
    // rename first element to last
    last_root = root;
    // reassign root to former second root
    root = next_root;
    // designate new root as head
    head = root;
    while (root != NULL) {
        if (root->next == NULL) {
            root->next = last_root;
            break;
        }
        root = root->next;
    }   
    return head;
}

int delete_first(Node_t *head){
    Node_t temp = (*head);
    // get data to be returned
    int val = (*head)->data;
    // reassign head to the second element
    *head = (*head)->next;
    // unlink former first element
    temp->next = NULL;
    return val;
}

void add_to_desk(Node_t *desk, Node_t temp){
    // check if desk is empty
    if ((*desk) == NULL) {
        // insert first element
        (*desk) = temp;
    }
    else {
        temp->next = (*desk);
        (*desk) = temp;
        //*desk = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    //initialize variables
    int val;
    int i;
    Node_t root, head;

    // set size of list of cards
    int n = 4;

    // allocate memory for temp list
    Node_t temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = 0;
    temp->next = NULL;

    // allocate memory for desk cards
    Node_t desk = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    desk->data = 0;
    desk->next = NULL;

    // allocate memory for list of cards
    Node_t list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node) * n);

    // initalize list with n cards
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        list[i].data = i+1;
        if (i == n-1) {
            list[i].next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            list[i].next = &list[i+1];
        }
    }

    printf("\nWe start with these cards in our hand:  ");
    root = &(list[0]);
    print_list(root);

    while (1){
        while (root != NULL){
            val = delete_first(&root);
            printf("We have removed the first card of our hand, val = %d\n",val);
            printf("New list:  ");
            print_list(root);
            printf("Lets add val %d to the stack on the desk\n",val);
            if (desk->data == 0) {
                printf("First time adding to desk stack\n");
                desk->data = val;
                desk->next = NULL;
            }
            else {
                temp->data = val;
                printf("Adding val %d to desk stack\n",val);
                add_to_desk(&desk,temp);
            }
            printf("New desk stack:  ");
            print_list(desk);

            if (root->next == NULL) {
                printf("We are at the last card of our hand, just throw it on the desk\n");
                temp->data = root->data;
                add_to_desk(&desk,temp);
                print_list(desk); // <--- HERE'S WHERE PRINTING GOES OUT OF CONTROL
                break;
            }
            else {
                head = first_to_last(root, head);
                root = head;
                printf("We have just moved the first card of our hand to the end\n");
                printf("New hand order:  ");            
                print_list(root);
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Print out:

```
Running…

We start with these cards in our hand:  1 2 3 4 
We have removed the first card of our hand, val = 1
New list:  2 3 4 
Lets add val 1 to the stack on the desk
First time adding to desk stack
New desk stack:  1 
We have just moved the first card of our hand to the end
New hand order:  3 4 2 
We have removed the first card of our hand, val = 3
New list:  4 2 
Lets add val 3 to the stack on the desk
Adding val 3 to desk stack
New desk stack:  3 1 
We have just moved the first card of our hand to the end
New hand order:  2 4 
We have removed the first card of our hand, val = 2
New list:  4 
Lets add val 2 to the stack on the desk
Adding val 2 to desk stack
New desk stack:  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...... 2's forever
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only allocate `temp` once, and then reuse it every time you add a card to the `desk`.

The first time you put a card on the desk there's no problem - you just set the value in the node you malloc'd and assigned to the variable `desk`.

Second time through, desk has been assigned, so you set the value in the node you malloc'd and assigned to variable `temp`, and update `desk` so that it points to that node.

The third time through is where the trouble starts. You set the value of `temp` to 2, but that `temp` is still the same object that you used last time (it's still the top of the desk.) You also update its `next` pointer to point to `desk` - which, again, is still the same node you originally malloc'd and assigned to `temp`.

In other words, `temp` and `desk` end up pointing to the same node in memory, which is pointing to itself. Trying to print this just means visiting the same card over and over again, which also means you never reach a null value, so you never stop.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it's also worth mentioning that when you `malloc` you should also `free` at some later date when the memory is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    temp->next = (*desk);
    (*desk) = temp;
    //*desk = temp;
}

try to understand this you will find your problem, as you are new so helping you in the
```

way that you can learn...:) it's from addtodeskfunc also read about circular linklist to get more help coz your codes give output like a points to b and b to a so null pointers never occuring to end the printing....

Answer (score 0):

This code wll properly work I have just remove * pointer in front of desk.
so it going to wrok.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} *Node_t;

void print_list(Node_t root) {
    while (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        root = root->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

Node_t first_to_last(Node_t root, Node_t head){
    Node_t next_root, last_root;
    // get the pointer to the second element
    next_root = root->next;
    // unlink first element
    root->next = NULL;
    // rename first element to last
last_root = root;
// reassign root to former second root
root = next_root;
// designate new root as head
head = root;
while (root != NULL) {
    if (root->next == NULL) {
        root->next = last_root;
        break;
    }
    root = root->next;
}   
return head;
}

int delete_first(Node_t *head){
Node_t temp = (*head);
// get data to be returned
int val = (*head)->data;
// reassign head to the second element
*head = (*head)->next;
// unlink former first element
temp->next = NULL;
return val;
 }

void add_to_desk(Node_t desk, Node_t temp){
// check if desk is empty
if ((desk) == NULL) {
    // insert first element
    (desk) = temp;
}
else {
    temp->next = (desk);
    (desk) = temp;
    //*desk = temp;
}
}

int main(){
//initialize variables
int val;
int i;
Node_t root, head;

// set size of list of cards
int n = 4;

// allocate memory for temp list
Node_t temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
temp->data = 0;
temp->next = NULL;

// allocate memory for desk cards
Node_t desk = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
desk->data = 0;
desk->next = NULL;

// allocate memory for list of cards
Node_t list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node) * n);

// initalize list with n cards
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    list[i].data = i+1;
    if (i == n-1) {
        list[i].next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        list[i].next = &list[i+1];
    }
}

printf("\nWe start with these cards in our hand:  ");
root = &(list[0]);
print_list(root);

while (1){
    while (root != NULL){
        val = delete_first(&root);
        printf("We have removed the first card of our hand, val = %d\n",val);
        printf("New list:  ");
        print_list(root);
        printf("Lets add val %d to the stack on the desk\n",val);
        if (desk->data == 0) {
            printf("First time adding to desk stack\n");
            desk->data = val;
            desk->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            temp->data = val;
            printf("Adding val %d to desk stack\n",val);
            add_to_desk(desk,temp);
        }
        printf("New desk stack:  ");
        print_list(desk);

        if (root->next == NULL) {
            printf("We are at the last card of our hand, just throw it on the desk\n");
            temp->data = root->data;
            add_to_desk(desk,temp);
            print_list(desk); // <--- HERE'S WHERE PRINTING GOES OUT OF CONTROL
            break;
        }
        else {
            head = first_to_last(root, head);
            root = head;
            printf("We have just moved the first card of our hand to the end\n");
            printf("New hand order:  ");            
            print_list(root);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
}
```